nginx try_files always falling to proxy
I have the following nginx config:
server {
    location ~ ^/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\.png$ {
        alias /mount/cache/c/$1/$2/$3.png;
        try_files $uri @proxy;
        add_header x-source file;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:28000;
        add_header x-source proxy;
    }
}

What I'm trying to achieve is to try to load the files from disk, and if they are not found only then ask the upstream for it.
My problem is that try_files doesn't seem to work, it always requests @proxy (x-source header is always proxy). If I comment out try_files then it loads the files from the disk correctly, but then the proxy part doesn't work.

You don't want to have try_files and alias in location defined with regexp. It's not well defined and noone actually knows how does (or should) it work. But it this example there is no need for alias at all.

In this example you don't need to use alias at all.
server {
    location ~ ^/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\.png$ {
        root /mount/cache/c;
        try_files $uri @proxy;
        add_header x-source file;
    }
    ...
}

If you need an alias, then don't use try_files. Use, for example, error_page.
server {
    location ~ ^/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\.png$ {
        alias /mount/cache/c/$1/$2/$3.png;
        add_header x-source file;

        error_page 404 = @proxy;
    }
    ...
}


Thanks a lot, I'd have never figured out the reason was alias!

The issue becomes from your alias directive.
Suppose a resource http://example.com/1/2/3.png is requested.
The alias directive means that nginx will look up a file at /mount/cache/c/1/2/3.png/1/2/3/.png. This is because alias sets the base path where files are located, and then the $uri is appended to the get the final resource.
This should work with this config:
server {
    location ~ ^/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\.png$ {
        alias /mount/cache/c;
        try_files $uri @proxy;
        add_header x-source file;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:28000;
        add_header x-source proxy;
    }
}

provided that your files are located in /mount/cache/c directory.

But documetation says “If alias is used inside a location defined with a regular expression then such regular expression should contain captures and alias should refer to these captures”

I suspect the documentation might be wrong here. Otherwise the implementation would be quite odd: when there are no variables from regex captures in the alias directive, then it refers to directory, and try_files works as normal. And when there are variables made from regex captures, then it refers to a file, and try_files would work in a different way.
